# Saída inesperada

Tags: bash, shell-script

Estou executando esse comando para remover linhas repetidas de um arquivo:

```
cat arquivo.csv | (read;echo "$REPLY"; sort) | uniq > arquivo.csv
```

Mas quando vou olhar o arquivo, ele está em branco ao invés de estar só com as linhas que não se repetem. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Sempre usei o `cat` | `sort` | `uniq` > `novo_nome`, se for com o mesmo nome ele fica sem conteúdo, agora não lembro qual era explicação para isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso usando apernas o sort.

```
sort -u arquivo.csv -o arquivo.csv
```

- `-u` vai remover as linhas duplicadas
- `-o` vai enviar a saída para o arquivo.csv

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o comando:

```
cat arquivo.csv | sort | uniq > novoArquivo.csv
```